# Predict an estimate based on image and numerical value

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict a number based on an image and a numerical value. To put it in a practical matter, let's say I am trying to add to the standard house price predictor an image. So among the other features (price, sqm, no of rooms, etc.) there will be an image. So ultimately, the price to be predicted will be based on the image supplied. Has that been implemented before? Also how can I add an image along with numbers as a feature? Is there an already project, I can use?

Comment: Yes. It will be a straightforward task of extracting features from images. Say save feature = model.predict(image_n),  then save features[image_n] = feature. So I don't think your confusion lies here. What you have to further do is along with other inputs for training, you have to use inputs as such model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs). Where inputs1 will be extracted features of each image, inputs2 will be other numerical input features available. It's wise to use layer_ = add([inputs1, inputs2]) after parsing them as inputs to neural network functions.

Answer (score 3):

The way I understand your question: how can I include information taken from a photo in the prediction of a house price?

- I assume, the picture can be classified into something like e.g. [mansion|villa|town house|beach house|shag]

This leaves you with:

- how would I make an ImageNet competitor (like VGG16) produce a string that gives me one of the 5 values?

The general idea is to use the pretrained ImageNet (here: VGG16) and remove some layers at the end, especially the one that normalizes the output into 1000 classes (BatchNormalization) and replace this layer with e.g. 5 outputs (see example classes above).

You need probably several thousand annotated images which you can use in batches to retrain your existing network (the pruned/altered VGG16).

I don't know which Deep Learning environment you are using, https://keras.io and https://caffe2.ai would be two of the currently most popular ones. Both have all the networks you mentioned in their Model Zoo or repository with pre-trained weights for the ImageNet data set.

Once you re-trained the DNN (and get high enough accuracy on you test image set), you can run it to get the best fitting class and use it as either one input for your next ML model either as a string/enumeration (by just using the best) or as 5 numbers with the certainty of the DNN for each of the 5 classes.

You can then use a NN again or basically any ML model as listed on the Data Mining Group's page for the PMML standard (http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/GeneralStructure.html).

SciKit learn (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn) has a bunch of them - if you are into Python - Random Forest or Support Vector Machine should produce reasonably good results if your data has a good quality.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You have two tasks.

1.Get features from the images as one of your inputs for your final prediction task. Or get predictions of images as your inputs for your final prediction task. 
2.The received feature extraction or made prediction of images should be used as another input along with other numerical value inputs say 'square feet', 'number of bedrooms'.

```
model = VGG16()
model.layers.pop()
model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[-1].output)
for image_name in listdir(directory_of_images):
    imagefile = path.join(directory_of_images, image_name)
    image = load_img(imagefile, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    feature = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
    image_id = imagename.split('.')[0]
    features[image_id] = feature
return features
```

Use these predicted features as your other input column along with 'numberOfBedroom', 'square_feet_length' columns of values to predict price.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the image features from any standard convolution nets (vgg16,vgg19 or googlenet) pretrained on imagenet. 
Concatenate image features with other features (price, sqm, no of rooms, etc.) and use this as input to a mlp to predict the house prices.